# split the string by last comma

Tags: jquery, string

I have string in jQuery.

```
var s = "Text1, Text2, Text,true";
```

I need split this variable in two part:

```
var s1 = substring(...); //after this s1="Text1, Text2, Text"
var s2 = substring(...); //after this s2="true"
```

Can you help me split variable?

Comment: You can use `.lastIndexOf(",")`.

Comment: actually you can use jquery `split()` function

Comment: @DrixsonOseña He didn't tag jQuery in the question, so including the library just to do that might be overkill. Especially as he could just use javascript's native split function

Comment: @TommyBs, oopps sorry didnt saw that. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var s="Text1, Text2, Text,true";
var lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf(",")

var s1 = s.substring(0, lastIndex); //after this s1="Text1, Text2, Text"
var s2 = s.substring(lastIndex + 1); //after this s2="true"
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer. +1

Comment: I dunno, it's performing lastIndexOf twice, efficiency teaches us to store return value from a function in a variable if we need to run the function more than once.

Comment: @Jimmy I also thought at that. :-) Updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
s1 = s.split(',');
s2 = s1.pop();
s1 = s1.join(',');
```

*(untestet)*

### Docs

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = s.lastIndexOf(",");
var first = str.substr(0, index );
var last = str.substr(index + 1);
```

Or using `slice`

```
var first = str.slice(0, index);
var last = str.slice(index +1);
```

Comment: The second argument is not required (`s.length`).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var array = s.match(/(.*),(.*)/);
var s1 = array[1];
var s2 = array[2]
```

Comment: Incidentally `/(.*),(.*)/` is also the emoticon for an astonished owl.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Text1, Text2, Text,true";
var n = s.lastIndexOf(",");

var s1 = s.substring(0, n);
var s2 = s.substring(n + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6yjr/